# Añadir elementos dimamicamente desde Javascript en el DOM

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, elementos

Buen@s a todos,

Podria alguien darme solucion a este ejercicio por favor ? Soy autodidacta y no tengo profe que me corrija

```
    <script>
    const $body = document.querySelector("body");
    const $div = document.createElement("div");

    $body.appendChild($div);
    
    const TECNOLOGIAS = [{url: 'reactjs.org',name: 'ReactJS'},{url: 'nodejs.org',name: 'NodeJS'}{url: 'graphql.org',name: 'GraphQL'}];   

  TECNOLOGIAS.forEach (params => {
    const $img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = `https:/logo.clearbit.com/${params.url}`;
    const $span = document.createElement("span");
    const $spanText = document.createTextNode(`${params.name}`);

  })
    $div.appendChild($img);
    $div.appendChild($span);
    $span.appendChild($spanText);
```

Pretendo crear a partir de Javascript los div con lo paramentros indicados sin pasar por HTML. Me parece haber creado bien la etiqueta Div dentro del body, y con el forEach he recorrido los elementos del array. Al final añado al Dic las img con su "url" y la etiqueta span con el texto "name".
La pantalla está en blanco, no hace caso a mi script.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Intenta ver si en la consola del navegador no te aparece algún error.

Answer (score 2):

había varios errores.

1. Referenciabas mal la variable, te faltaba $ y tenías mal la URL:

```
  const $img = document.createElement("img");
  $img.src = `https://logo.clearbit.com/${params.url}`;
```

2. Creabas las variables en el ciclo pero los usabas fuera, no se encontraban en el mismo ámbito:

```
TECNOLOGIAS.forEach (params => {
  const $img = document.createElement("img");
  $img.src = `https://logo.clearbit.com/${params.url}`;
  const $span = document.createElement("span");
  const $spanText = document.createTextNode(`${params.name}`);
  $div.appendChild($img);
  $div.appendChild($span);
  $span.appendChild($spanText);
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Tiene varios errores de compilación y uno de programación

1. const TECNOLOGIAS le falta una coma separadora entre urls
2. img.src es con el $ delante
3. los appendChild van dentro del bucle foreach

Eso a simple vista.

```
const TECNOLOGIAS = [{url: 'reactjs.org',name: 'ReactJS'},{url: 'nodejs.org',name: 'NodeJS'},{url: 'graphql.org',name: 'GraphQL'}];   

 $div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

introducir el código aquí
```